# How to adjust Report Field Height at run time

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

I'd like to adjust Report field height at run time. Please see my report design and review with data below

[image: Report Design]

[image: Report Review with data]

1. In the 2nd image, at the 3rd and 4th row of "Wine" column, if the
   data length is enough for a line, I'd like to adjust its height into
   a line (**And also bottom line object be followed by it**). Otherwise, let it be two lines. Please share me which
   property I'd set.

PS: In page header, I use box object. But in Details section, I just use line object because in report footer, I need to show Total amount. If I use a box in these three sections, there is the box is expanded the whole page without having detail rows at the last page. I'm not a report expert. If I'm wrong in something, pls feel free to tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal will never shorten boxes, lines, or fields, so you need to make them small and mark them **Can Grow**. Here's a way to do that and make the line draw below the field, even if the field does grow.

1. Mark the text field **Can Grow**.
2. Shrink the text field down to the minimum, one-line size you want.
3. Right-click the detail section and select **Add Section Below**.
4. Move the horizontal line at the bottom of the first detail section to the top of the new detail section, and extend the vertical lines down to it.
5. Shrink both the detail sections tight to their contents.